# How can I get an anchor tag with no or empty href in typo3 ckeditor

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, ckeditor4.x, typo3-8.x

In TYPO3 8.7, I'm trying to create an anchor tag to open a modal, in a regular text element, like this:

```
<a class="someclass" data-open="myModal">Click me</a>
```

But Typo3 will automatically add an href attribute linking to the current page. When I click the tag, the modal opens, but the page immediately reloads.

I've tryed adding `href="#"`, but that turns into `href="/mypage/#"` and `href="#mymodal"` becomes `href="/mypage/#mymodal"`, both of which trigger a reload.

In my ckeditor setup, I have set `allowedContent: true`

How can I make an `<a>` tag without the href being altered?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ClickEvent on an a-tag you need to return `false` from the javascript to stop further processing. And following the link is the last *further* processing.

Even if you manage to reduce the href to `#` you page may reload or jump to the start.

Maybe you can fool your browser if you use `href="javascript:return false"`.

Comment: Adding `href="javascript:return false"` causes Typo3 to remove the `<a>` tag entirely when displaying the page, although it still shows in the editor. Also, in my case I've tested `href="#"` and it works, I just can't get it through TYPO3 to the page.

Comment: declare the javascript call as external url (those urls normaly stay untouched) `data-htmlarea-external="1"`

Comment: I've also tried with the above method. But it is not working for me. Is there any configuration in ckeditor to disable the hrefin a tag?